# How to create an Item Count table in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to create a nice table in excel to show instances of items.

I have two sheets. One with all possible items listed in a column (800 rows) and the second with instances of the item being used. The first sheet is a single column. The second sheet is 3 columns; Record Number (these are tickets in a ticketing system), the item the record was generated from, and the date it was generated.

I would like a table to show ALL items from sheet 1 and then a count of how many times that item generated a record. I have many items that have never been used so the count would be zero. Every table I have tried to create thus far filters out items that were un-used.

How would I build such a thing?

Some sample data to explain things better hopefully. The list of Items is 800 rows, the list of records is a little over 31000.

Sheet 1:One column with list of items

```
Item
Request for Computer
Request for Software
Request for Phone
Request for Monitor
Request for Mailbox
Request for Application Access
```

Sheet 2: Three columns with records resulting from submission of request

```
Number         Item                     Date Submitted
RITM000001     Request for Computer     1-1-2020
RITM000002     Request for Computer     1-1-2020
RITM000003     Request for Computer     1-1-2020
RITM000004     Request for Computer     1-1-2020
RITM000005     Request for Software     1-1-2020
RITM000006     Request for Computer     1-1-2020
RITM000007     Request for Computer     1-1-2020
RITM000008     Request for Computer     1-1-2020
RITM000009     Request for Software     1-1-2020
RITM000010     Request for Computer     1-1-2020
RITM000011     Request for Monitor      1-1-2020
```

Results I am looking for would be on Sheet 3:

```
Table:
Item                              Item Used Count
Request for Computer              8
Request for Software              2
Request for Phone                 0
Request for Monitor               1
Request for Mailbox               0
Request for Application Access    0
```

Comment: Use COUNTIFS().

Comment: Welcome to Super User,, please [edit] your post & share some sample data from both sheets, also  be clear and loud that  what you are expecting as OUTPUT.

Answer (score 0):

As given by you :
Worksheet 1 ; 2 Columns : [ Item No ];  [ Instances ].
Worksheet 2 ; 3 Columns : [ Record No. ]; [ Item Used ]; [ Date ]

Now Worksheet 1 ; In Cell B2 Enter the following formula

B2 = COUNTIF(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$1001,Sheet1!A2)

Copy this formula down the column, in B3, B4,....    B1001.

To get the desired result.

It is for say 1000 records and $B$2...reference is used so that when you copy down the column, reference remains SAME.

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your post & share some sample data to justify the formula U have applied !!

Comment: Not understood by me, what you require. If you see the question I have answered, it is very easy to create 2 worksheets, as described in the question one can create himself two worksheets and enter the formula given by me. If you are not satisfied, I dont know how to put worksheets here. You please guide me to answer your question, I am at your service.

Comment: While answering also copy and paste dont work. So I have to rewrite the formula I used in worksheet. My answer format is also changed, I had written two rows for clarity.... but it get mixed to one row. The point is I am new, so I dont know.

Comment: Hey @ Harshad Amichand Vegda ,,, [Check this,,](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) ☺

Answer (score 0):

Last time my answer was not clear to others.

With a small data I am sending it again.

R1 is in A5, then B5 etc. R30 is A34, then B34...

Therefore Area for Counting is B5 to B34.

For Absolute Reference,it is $B$5:$B$34 etc.

The formula is entered in Instances Column.

As soon as you edit the data, results are changed accordingly.

I hope it is clear. I found it very very difficult and tiresome to Copy Excel Worksheet Area and Paste it directly as my answer.

I totally dont know how to use Excel Worksheet directly as an answer because there is no provision, or I am unaware.

Thanks.

[image]